# Unrecognised selector crash within [NSDictionary valueForKey:]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm occasionally getting this crash, which is very hard to reproduce:

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x39ff73e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3905095e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x39ffaf2c -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 180
3   CoreFoundation                  0x39ff9648 ___forwarding___ + 388
4   CoreFoundation                  0x39f51204 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   Foundation                      0x32914bec -[NSDictionary(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 28
6   MyAppName                       0x00032112 -[myViewController stopPlayersWithVolume:] (myViewController.m:151)
```

From this code:

```
- (void)stopPlayersWithVolume:(double)volume
{
    for (NSString *file in players)
    {
        AVAudioPlayer *player = [players valueForKey:file];
        if (player.volume == volume || volume == 0)
            [player stop];
    }
}
```

`players` is an `NSMutableDictionary` property, accessed without `self.` because I don't believe it's needed with ARC. The keys are filenames (e.g. "mysound.mp3") and the values are `AVAudioPlayer` objects.

Is the stack trace saying that the parameter `file` I'm passing to `[NSMutableDictionary valueForKey]` is not actually an `NSString`, and hence the unrecognised selector? It is always an `NSString` in the debugger, as you'd expect as it comes from a fast enumeration through the dictionary, but the crash never occurs in the debugger.

My only thought is that there's a threading issue corrupting the dictionary. The code above is being fired by an NSTimer but that's just a message via the run loop, not a separate thread, so I believe there should be no need to worry about cross-thread access?

Any suggestions appreciated. Sorry to just dump this out but I'm stuck.

**Edit:**

The players dictionary is allocated in `viewDidLoad` thus:

```
players = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

And declared as follows:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *players;
```

And synthesised as follows:

```
@synthesize players;
```

Comment: What is the key? `valueForKey` does some m@gic that `objectForKey` does not.

Comment: It looks to me that although the players object is defined as an NSMutableDictionary it is pointing to an object of another class (maybe it is as an NSArray?).

Comment: Could you copy and paste the literal error message?  There might be some clue in the details.  (Break on Objective-C exceptions if it's not currently logging an exception message.)

Comment: I only have the crash dump from Organizer, do you want that? There's no exception message in there, just `Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000`

Comment: @Thilo, I've edited the first paragraph to explain what the keys are, is that what you meant?

Comment: Can you show the lines where you assign the players property?

Comment: How about wrapping the lines inside your `for` loop in a @try/@catch section and putting `NSLog(@"%@: %@", [exception description], file);` in the @catch part.  The result should show on the device console even if you don't get an error while debugging.

Comment: @DiederikHoogenboom, have edited to include the players property as per req.

Comment: How do you fill the dict? Doesn't it need to be `AVAudioPlayer *player = [players objectForKey:file];` instead of `valueForKey`?

Comment: @ott, it was indeed the filling/allocation of the dictionary, details such as they are in my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to allocate the dictionary (and set up the audio stuff) looked like this:

```
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSArray *names = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:resourcePath error:&error];
players = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
```

I must have copied and pasted it from somewhere, because that use of `NSError` is wrong, as far as I know, though hardly likely to cause a problem. I changed the code to this:

```
NSArray *names = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:resourcePath error:nil];
players = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

And the problem goes away, it appears. Can't be 100% sure but I can reproduce the crash within 10 attempts with the former code and never with the latter. No idea why.

Comment: If you want to use the error output of the method, you just declare the variable: NSError *error; You don't alloc init it. The method itself, creates the error object, it just needs a place to put it.

Comment: The app's in production now and never crashes. So it appears that using NSError wrongly as above causes crashing.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your `players` dictionary or its contents are being deallocated while you're iterating through them. Can you turn on [NSZombies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) and try to reproduce the crash in the debugger? It will give you more information about what object is being deallocated.

Comment: And one little style thing: with a dictionary, you probably want to use ```objectForKey:```, not ```valueForKey:```, though this is probably not the problem.

Comment: Yes I've done a lot of profiling with NSZombies enabled but nothing came up. I allocate the dictionary like this: `players = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];` which I momentarily thought was the problem as I missed `self.`, but you don't need it with ARC to get the retain, do you?

Comment: Agreed, I should have used `objectForKey:`. Have learned lots about NSDictionary today...

Comment: If this is pre-iOS 6, try running in the simulator and causing memory warnings. Is it possible your timer keeps running after you leave this view controller, for example?